# WebStorm shortcut commands

Tags: webstorm, shortcut

What are the shortcut tab commands, such as cw -> Console.Writeline() in VS and sout -> System.out.println() in InteliJ, for WebStorm?

Or where can I find them? Googling phrases such as "WebStorm shortcuts" and "WebStorm shortcut phrases" only give me the ordinary keyboard shortcuts, which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/live-templates-2.html).

You can find them under `Settings > Editor > Live Templates`.

The template for `System.out.print()` is `sout`.